# Read JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am creating a web service to take the input  in **JSON**. Please see the code below:

**Registration.asmx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using AnkTech.IsItFair.WebService.Providers;
using System.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Registration
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Registration : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public int SaveUser()
        {
            string json =
                @"{""data"":[{""Id"":""518523721"",""Name"":""ftyft""}]}";

            Users tempRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(json);
            return 1;

        }
    }
}
```

**Users.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebService.Providers
{

    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Users
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I check my object **tempRecord**, I found the null values of my both properties i.e.**Id** and **Name**. What I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Try to remove `data` (use a list of objects, something like: `[{"Id": 1, "Name": "Foo"}, {...} , {...}]`) from your JSON example, rename your class to `User` and deserialize using a `List<User>`. And read the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing it by REST then you can do like this

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/index")]
```

to Deserialize the json

```
var userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
```

to serialize the json

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeList, Formatting.Indented);
```

for serialization and deserialization and more documentation you can go to [Documentation of Newtonsoft json](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html#)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a new poco class, e.g.

```
    public class UserData
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public IList<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

and then

```
    var tempRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(json);
```

It should work.